# batch file for finding a particular file in a sorted directory

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-processing

I need to sort all the sub-folders in a directory and print the first folder that contains a file, i tried using

```
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "directorypath" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO SET a=%%i
IF EXIST a\*.exe
echo folder %a%
```

in line 1 i tried sorting the folders in the directory based on date modified
and then searched for .exe in each folder and print the latest folder which contains an exe.
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you want the most recently modified or created directory name containing any `.exe` file, or do you want the directory name containing the most recently modified or created `.exe` file. In your response please ensure that you are specific for both files and directories whether you want `modified` or `created`, there could be a marked difference between those and possibly the methods used to determine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based purely on your question without response to my comment, I'm going to assume you wish to do something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "dP=directorypath"
Set "dN="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir/B/AD-S-L-H/OD/TC "%dP%" 2^>Nul'
) Do If Exist "%dP%\%%A\*.exe" Set "dN=%%A"
If defined dN Echo %dN%
Pause
```

*Just modify `directorypath` on line two to suit your full or relative source directory.*

Comment: This works perfectly, but since my directory is huge it takes some time to find, i tried appending something like "dp=directorypath/te*", so that it sorts folders with name starting with te followed by the rest of the name which can change for each folder but it did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question was specific to "latest", the sort is designed for that. If you change the sort method, the question becomes obsolete as does the answer.

Comment: Ok, so do you have any other suggestion for getting the results faster